# Cómo combinar colecciones que incluyen arrays en laravel

Tags: laravel, array

tengo este array que incluye n cantidad de items, esos items son colecciones que incluyen arrays dentro, este es

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1754 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "OFFER" => "OFFER"
        "STANDARD" => "STANDARD"
        "EVENT" => "EVENT"
      ]
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1731 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        "EVENT" => "EVENT"
```

quisiera integrar todos estos items en una sola colección y que no repita las mismas palabras ("EVENT" está en ambas colecciones de arriba): por ejemplo

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1636 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      "OFFER" => "OFFER"
      "STANDARD" => "STANDARD"
      "EVENT" => "EVENT"
```

Es posible? de ser así cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero transformás el array en una colección y después usas el método [`collapse()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-collapse).

Eso combina todo en un solo nivel y no repite las claves del array. No se si es eso lo que necesitás porque en tu ejemplo las claves y los valores son iguales, no se si es siempre así.

```
// Transformá el array en una colección
$array = collect($array);

// Collapse
$array = $array->collapse();
```

Comment: sí, siempre serán iguales las claves y los valores, así me devuelve el resultado una API, lo probaré gracias